# How can I get the video resolution on html file input before uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, html-input

When I select a video file on HTML file input, I want to get the video resolution(width & height) and all the metadata(size, length, file type, etc if possible).I need a js or jquery solution for this. I couldn't find anything related to this topic. Help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out this answer describing mediainfo.js. the demo linked seems to fulfill your requirements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56477757/12533555

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to do this. I hope this will be useful to someone.

When a video file added to the file input, we create a new `video` element and load the file into the `video`'s `src` attribute. We then add an event listener to the `loadedmetadata` event of the video tag and there we can get the video height and width.

```html
<input type="file" class="file_multi_video" />

<script>
    $(document).on("change", ".file_multi_video", function(evt) {
       const video = document.createElement('video')
       video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', event => {
           console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
       });
       video.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
    });
</script>
```